# Assembly source cannot pass arguments correctly

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I have two source files, one in assembly and one in c. The assembly contains a reference to a static string in the c source. I define a function in the assembly that is called from the c source, and it works fine without any hitches. But when I attempt to call printf from the assembly and pass a string from the c source file as an argument, I get garbled output or none at all.

I compile the assembly into an elf32-i386 using nasm, and the c file using gcc. I've tried with and without debugging information and got the same results, fortunately.

Here are the simple source files:

main.s:

```
SECTION .text

global s_func
extern c_str
extern printf

s_func:
    sub esp, 4
    mov dword [esp], c_str
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    ret
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char* c_str = "Sup."; 
extern void s_func(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf(c_str); //prints as expected
    s_func(); //weird stuff
}
```

Makefile:

```
main : main.o main.s.o
    gcc main.o main.s.o -o main

main.o :
    gcc -g -c main.c -o main.o
main.s.o :
    nasm -f elf main.s -o main.s.o
```

Here's the part that gets me, if you compiled these two files into objects then linked them together, you'll find that the call to printf is no different is either sources. Code segments are the same, and the c_str contains the same address in both assembly listings.

call in main.c:

```
    printf(c_str); //prints as expected
 80483ed:   a1 14 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a014,%eax
 80483f2:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80483f5:   e8 06 ff ff ff          call   8048300 <printf@plt>
```

call in main.s

```
08048410 <s_func>:
 8048410:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 8048413:   b8 14 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a014,%eax
 8048418:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 804841b:   e8 e0 fe ff ff          call   8048300 <printf@plt>
 8048420:   83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
 8048423:   c3                      ret
```

Maybe I'm suppose to preserve some registers? I've setup a normal stackframe on s_func but yes it still fails.

Comment: It looks like you are pushing the address of c_str instead of its value. Step through the code in the debugger.

Comment: c_str is a pointer to as it should be. Plus it's exactly the same in main.c. Does the $ symbol have any significance?

Comment: The code gen in main.s does not match the source code. Your original code did not load eax. Something doesn't add up. Maybe you're looking at the wrong code.

Comment: Yeah I was gonna answer my question but my rep is too low to answer it now. Loading eax isn't the problem, they are seemingly the same logic. I found out the problem, the move opcode A1 is effectively `mov eax, [c_str]`, the missing '$' denotes this but is odd in that the address, not the address of the address, points to the appropriate string .rodata section. I'm guessing there's an intermediate process in elfs that tables out all strings before the code starts?

Comment: Nvm, not tables. The fact it's a string pointer required the deference in main.s. However if it was `const char[]` then I would not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem while linking object files(due to the used of print in assembly).

I think the best way is create a GAS assembly that contain a function to use printf of c library, and then use "as" command to assemble the file.

Then use gcc compiler to compile the c code and link the GAS created object file in one line by using the following command.

if GAS created object file is main_s.o,

```
gcc main_c.c main_s.o -o main
```

So gcc first create the object format of main_c.c then link both main_c.o and main_s.o, it will give the currect linked elf file.